# Docker run Java keytool command in Dockerfile runs indefinitely during build only on MacOS

Tags: java, docker, macos, dockerfile, keytool

I have the following dockerfile (simplified for clarity):

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/k0l5c1j7/openjdk-8-jdk-alpine:latest

COPY bigDataSelfSignedRoot.pem $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
RUN cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias aliasName -file selfSignedRoot.pem
```

In the same folder is a certificate selfSignedRoot.pem

When executing this on a windows machine:

```
docker build -t appname:0.1 .
```

it builds successfully, **however** on a MacBook Pro (macOS Monterey Apple M1 pro),
the docker build gets stuck at the RUN step with the execution timer just running indefinitely.

Any reason why it would work on Windows but not Mac?

Comment: I have the same issue, Macbook Pro 14" M1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try renaming the PEM file, it worked for me. Do not ask me why.